# Contar valores repetidos con UcanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, sql, números-enteros

Como puedo contar los valores repetidos con UcanAccess accediendo a un campo de una base de datos en Access

```
 try {

        String sql = "select "+Campo+" , count("+Campo+") from Bicicletas group by "+Campo+" having count("+Campo+")>1";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet Resultado = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(Resultado.next()){
            System.out.println("Tamaño de la lista:"+Resultado.getString(1));
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Necesito que `Resultado` sea un entero pero no encuentro una funcion acorde a eso, solo logro imprimir los valores que tienen repeticion
Ejemplo:

```
Tamaño de la lista:Niño
Tamaño de la lista:Mujer
Tamaño de la lista:Hombre
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. ¿Has comprobado si tu sentencia SQL devuelve los valores correctos que necesitas?

Comment: Claro, si los devuelve, pero como lo puedo traspasar a un entero?